# Mount an USB key drive VFAT file system as user, or at least having writing rights on its contents

Tags: mount, vfat

I'm trying to mount a `VFAT` file system placed on a USB key drive, so that I can manipulate the drive contents.

```
12:10 boffi@debian:~ $ lsblk | grep sdc
sdc      8:32   1   7.5G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   1   7.5G  0 part 
12:10 boffi@debian:~ $ grep sdc /etc/fstab
/dev/sdc       /home/boffi/key           vfat    noauto,rw,user                   0       0 
/dev/sdc1      /home/boffi/key           vfat    noauto,rw,user                   0       0 
12:11 boffi@debian:~ $ mount /dev/sdc1 /home/boffi/key
mount: /home/boffi/key: must be superuser to use mount.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
12:11 boffi@debian:~ $
```

If I use `sudo` everything is fine, except I have no writing rights on the contents...

```
12:17 boffi@debian:~ $ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /home/boffi/key
[sudo] password for boffi: ***************
12:17 boffi@debian:~ $ ls -l key | head -3
total 27600
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root    16384 Oct  6  2013 00_roba_dal_mac/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    16384 Oct 12  2013 00_shenker/
12:17 boffi@debian:~ $
```

Of course I'm doing something wrong, could you please help me?

Comment: The following link to my [answer at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072) may help you solve the problem.

Comment: @sudodus Works like a charm, unfortunately I've not joined the AU community and I cannot reward you with an upvote. To anyone_else, if you went to AskUbuntu following the link, please upvote!

Comment: Thanks for telling us that you have solved your problem :-) Please feel free to write an answer and 'accept' it to make it easy for new users to see that there is a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disclaimer

The following is stolen from an [AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072) that the [Author](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/292180/sudodus) kindly showed me in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/713907/mount-an-usb-key-drive-vfat-file-system-as-user-or-at-least-having-writing-righ?noredirect=1#comment1352312_713907) to my question.
If my answer is useful to you, please remember to thank [sudodus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/292180/sudodus), not me and possibly up-vote the original [AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072).

### Answer

As far as I have understood, you need `root` privileges to execute the `mount` command, so you must login as `root`, or use `sudo`.

It is however possible to have the requested behavior, because passing to the `mount` command appropriate options you can have appropriate
owner, group and permissions.

You can specify the user and group assigned to the mounted drive content using the numeric user and group ID, you can specify the permissions using a suitable creation mask, as follows:

```
$ sudo mount -o rw,user,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=007,exec /dev/sdc1 /home/boffi/key
```

To determine your UID and GID

```
$ grep `whoami` /etc/passwd | mawk -F: '{print $3, $4}'
1000 1000
```

Because I have this line in `/etc/fstab`

```
$ grep /sdc1 /etc/fstab
/dev/sdc1 /home/boffi/key vfat noauto,rw,user 0 0
```

I can omit the mount point from the  command...

```
$ sudo mount -o rw,user,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=007,exec /dev/sdc1
```

Just a check of the correctness of the command that was executed.

```
$ ls -l key | head -3
total 27600
drwxrwx---  6 boffi boffi    16384 Oct  6  2013 00_roba_dal_mac/
drwxrwx---  4 boffi boffi    16384 Oct 12  2013 00_shenker/
$
```

As you can see, the owner and the group are correct and the permissions are those specified by the `umask` used during the mount operation.

Answer (score 0):

Your windows manager should mount it somewhat automatically. If not, you could always add something similar to this to `/etc/fstab` - `/dev/sdc1 /media vfat,iso9660,udf  user,defaults,noauto 0 0`. Check the fstab man page for details. You just need to run `mount /media` as any user and that user will have "own" it and have full permissions. Remember to create the `media` or similar directory.

Comment: `twm` is somehow defective when it comes to automagically mount external drives. ፨፨፨ Also, I don't want that the drive is automatically mounted under `/media`, I want to mount it when I need it, in a different location.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the `noauto` option. This will ensure it will only be mounted manually. Again, see the man page.